# Setting text color in TikZ without changing line color; conflict with double

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

I have a certain Ti*k*Z style that I would like to use over and over again (so I'd like to use it as a scope). Namely, I want the color of the curves to be red, with white borders (to give a "crossing over" effect when the curves go over each other), and I want the color of the text to be red too. Currently I am using the `double` effect to accomplish this, like so:

```
\tikzset{curveinscope/.style={
    every path/.style={
        draw=white, double distance=1pt, line width=2pt, double=red, color=red}
    }
}
```

However this clashes with the `double` effect: setting `color=red` to make the text color red sets the drawing color of the first line in the `double` to also be red, which messes up the effect (it needs to be white).

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You should set the color using `text=red` instead of `color=red`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzset{curveinscope/.style={every path/.style={draw=white, double distance=1pt, line width=2pt, double=red, text=red}}}

\begin{scope}[curveinscope]
\node at (1,0) {X};
\draw (0,0) -- (2,2);
\draw (2,1) -- (0,1);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I _knew_ there was a text-specific colour option but tried `text color` first and got an error.  Next time, I'll check the manual before posting.

Comment: @Andrew: Hehe, I did exactly the same thing (trying `text color` first, that is). Maybe there should be an alias for the option.

Comment: I have a memory of a `text color` option.  Maybe it was an older version of PGF that was dropped in favour of the more concise `text=colour`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I couldn't find that text=red color option in the manual. This is definitely a simple solution :-)

Comment: @Bruce: Section 16.4.1 in the manual for PGF2.10.

Answer (score 10):

Separate your path-specific options from your node-specific ones.  Put the node-specific ones in an `every node/.style`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{curve in scope/.style={
    every path/.style={
      draw=white,
      double distance=1pt,
      line width=2pt,
      double=red,
    },
    every node/.style={
      color=red
    }
  },
  curve in scope with bad colours/.style={
    every path/.style={
      draw=white,
      double distance=1pt,
      line width=2pt,
      double=red,
      color=red
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[curve in scope]
\path (0,0) -- node[auto] {hello world} (3,0);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[curve in scope with bad colours,yshift=-1cm]
\path (0,0) -- node[auto] {hello world} (3,0);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: colours on paths and nodes]

Comment: Thanks Andrew, this teaches me some good practice here. I didn't know about the every node option.

Comment: @Bruce: Yes, whilst Jake's is the more concise of the solutions, I think that the principle of separation is worth pointing out too.